# Kotlin. Перегрузка методов под тип Null

Tags: kotlin, интерфейс, null

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь реализовать интерфейс примерно такого вида:

```
interface IDataConversions {
    fun setData(value: Boolean?)
    fun setData(value: Byte?)
    fun setData(value: Short?)
    fun setData(value: Int?)
    fun setData(value: Float?)
    fun setData(value: ByteArray?)
    fun setData(value: String?)
}
```

Однако заметил, что в таком случае придется в каждом методе проверять на Null

Есть возможность в `Kotlin` реализовать что-то типа такого? :

```
interface IDataConversions {
    fun setData(value: "какой то Null тип")
    fun setData(value: Boolean)
    fun setData(value: Byte)
    fun setData(value: Short)
    fun setData(value: Int)
    fun setData(value: Float)
    fun setData(value: ByteArray)
    fun setData(value: String)
}
```

Comment: Не понял, вы пытаетесь описать интерфейс или реализовать его?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, описать интерфейс. Потом само собой описать его для нужных мне классов. Я хотел, чтобы только один метод принимал null, чтобы не делать проверку на null по сто раз. Но , похоже так не выдет

Comment: Пока вижу только вариант **setData(value : Any?)** , а далее проверять объекты по типу

Comment: Может вам просто `setDataToNull()` стоит добавить? Объясните кейс, в чем задача этого интерфейса?

Comment: Для визуализации данных от устройств по протоколу Modbus. Там данные представляются 16 битовыми регистрами или битами. Пользователем формирует, как конкретные ячейки читать. Создавая наборы "сигналов" нужного типа. Байты того же float сигнала разложить по разному. Подсоединяя выход "сигнала" к входу другого "сигнала" должна быть реализована конвертация. @EugeneKrivenja

Comment: Вот что-то схожее реализовано у человека в видео. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUk8NqLWirk

Comment: @levWi самый разумный вариант. Благо есть `when`

Answer (score 1):

Также, как и в джаве, при перегрузке будет браться сначала более конкретный тип. Выглядит так, что вам просто нужно перегрузить метод с параметром `Any?`:

```
interface IDataConversions {
    fun setData(value: Any?)
    fun setData(value: Boolean)
    fun setData(value: Byte)
    ...
}
```